# How can I set the x axis label values without it affecting my graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe that's a few thousand rows long and I want to plot them with Matplotlib.

```py
temps = df['temperature']
plt.plot(temps)
```

I want the values along the x-axis to start at 0 and end with 25.
Something like this:

```
|
|
|
|
|
|
|________________________
0   5   10   15   20   25
```

How do I do that without it affecting my plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Set xlim

You can use the [`plt.xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) function.

```py
temps = df['temperature']
plt.plot(temps)
plt.xlim(0, 25)
```

However `matplotlib` documentation is pushing for everyone to use their object-oriented api and stay away from the high level `plt` plotting functions. In this case we'll set the xlimits with [`Axes.set_xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html)

```py
temps = df['temperature']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(temps)
ax.set_xlim(0, 25)
```

### Set xticks

Now if you wan to control the number of ticks along your x-axis, you can manually set them like so:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(temps)
ax.set_xlim(0, 25)
ax.set_xticks([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25])
```

Or you can use the `.ticker` API like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

temps = [i ** 2 for i in range(25)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(temps)
ax.set_xlim(0, 25)

# from the lower x-limit to the upper x-limit
#  place a tick every multiple of 5
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
```

### Using Many Values

If you have more than 25 values and want to place them on an arbitrary 0-25 scale, you can use a tick locator and tick formatter like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator

temps = [i ** 2 for i in range(1_000)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(temps)
ax.margins(x=0)

n = 6 # ticks including: 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(n))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda val, pos: pos * (n - 1))
```

[image]